# Wrap text onto other side of a grid cell with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Given this html structure, where **LLGrid** is displayed as *grid* in CSS, how can I make sure that my text is wrapped into the same cell, as if it was divided into two columns?

I did not manage to find a way to program the text to do this, so it keeps overflowing outside of the cell because it is too long.

[image: Result]

```css
.LLgrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: red;
  position: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 1400px;
}

.cell {
  /* center the cell content */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: white;
  width: 680px;
  height: 150px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="LLcontainer">
  <div class="LLgrid">
    <div class="cell" id="1"> one
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <p>Very very long text <br> Broken into multiple lines </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell" id="2"> two </div>
    <div class="cell" id="3"> three </div>
    <div class="cell" id="4"> four </div>
    <div class="cell" id="5"> five </div>
    <div class="cell" id="6"> six </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 08 September 2021:**

is subordinated to  (whose CSS is posted below). So when I apply the solution proposed by **Jonty** I still have messy cells. I am running now the CSS as for the [Demo1][2] Snippet.

```
.screen {
    width: 1450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 24px;
    font-family: verdana, arial;
    text-align: center;
    background: #130a06;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to deploy a solution of my own.

I removed the suggested inner div *row, column* and I operated on the **div class="cell"** directly.

On CSS I used the *column* attributes to get the text displayed as I need. Afterwards I formatted the text to be visible in its entirety.

This solution is the best fit for me, as the page is meant to be static (it will serve as a dashboard and not as a website, therefore I count with some rigidity).

```
.cell {
  justify-content: center;
  column-count: 3;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: white;
  width: 848px;
  height: 310px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  /*Column Style*/
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 40px;
  column-rule-width: 440px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the content into separate columns and apply `display:flex;` to the row and `min-width: 100%;` to the columns so they read vertically: - [demo](https://codepen.io/jonty_w/pen/QWgbYrx)

Alternatively you could apply `display:flex;` & `flex-wrap:wrap;` to the column, but they content will read horizontally. - [demo](https://codepen.io/jonty_w/pen/MWowLXZ)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works until a certain point but for a different reason I believe. See, the <div class="LLgrid"> is itself in another div (class="screen"). I edited my original question so you can see the CSS. The spacing of the cells then does not match anymore as the text do not align to the columns.

Comment: Hi, 

Any solution for this will only work up to a certain point because the grid cell has an absolute height (150px) therefore you physically can't fit in an unlimited amount of text into 150px by 680px.

One further solution would be to change `height: 150px;` to `min-height: 150px;` as this will allow the cells to vertically expand to fit in more text.

There may be a better solution depending on what you want to achieve. If you could provide more information on exactly what you want to achieve and whether height/width must be finite I may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Demo for vertical align - https://codepen.io/jonty_w/pen/QWgbYrx
Demo for horizontal align - https://codepen.io/jonty_w/pen/MWowLXZ